# Cuda warp illegal address

Tags: class, memory, cuda

I'm having some trouble with CUDA and passing classes to a kernel. I've some functions which allocate memory for the class on the GPU, pass it, and work fine. There is another one, though, that just won't work. I noticed that it happens only when I'm working with arrays. Here is an example.

File1.hh

```
#ifndef PROVA1_HH
#define PROVA1_HH

#include <cstdio>

class cls {
public:
    int *x, y;
    cls();  
    void kernel();
};

#endif
```

File1.cu

```
#include "Prova1.hh"

__global__ void kernel1(cls* c){
    printf("%d\n", c->y);
    c->y=2;
    printf("%d\n", c->y);
    c->x[0]=0; c->x[1]=1;
    printf("%d %d\n", c->x[0], c->x[1]);
}

void cls::kernel(){
    cls* dev_c; cudaMalloc(&dev_c, sizeof(cls));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_c, this, sizeof(cls), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    printf("(%d, %d)\n", x[0], x[1]);
    kernel1<<<1, 1>>> (dev_c);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(this, dev_c, sizeof(cls), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("(%d, %d)\n", x[0], x[1]);
}

cls::cls(){
    y=3;
    x=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    x[0]=1; x[1]=2;
}
```

File.cu

```
#include<cstdio>
#include "Prova1.hh"

int main(){
    cls c=cls();
    c.kernel();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling with:

```
nvcc -std=c++11 -arch=sm_35 -rdc=true -c -o File1.o File1.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -arch=sm_35 -rdc=true -g -G -o File.out File1.o File.cu
```

When I simpy run it, the output would be:

```
(1, 2)
3
2
(1, 2)
```

When I debug it, I get:

```
Starting program: 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fb10eb1e0 (LWP 806)]
(1, 2)

CUDA Exception: Warp Illegal Address
The exception was triggered at PC 0x84fa10

Thread 1 "File.out" received signal CUDA_EXCEPTION_14, Warp Illegal Address.
[Switching focus to CUDA kernel 0, grid 1, block (0,0,0), thread (0,0,0), device 0, sm 0, warp 0, lane 0]
0x000000000084fad0 in kernel1(ciao*)<<<(1,1,1),(1,1,1)>>> ()
```

Do any of you guys know were I'm making mistakes?

Comment: How do you imagine `dev_c->x` will ever have device memory allocated for it?

Comment: I allocated memory in cls::kernel(). Isn't that enough?

Comment: No you didn't allocate memory for `dev_c->x`. In your host constructor, there is a malloc call for `cls.x`. There is no equivalent for `dev_c`.

Comment: Ah, now I'm getting it. So I should allocate memory for cls ad dev_c, than for dev_c.x... Right?

Comment: No, not really. You can't modify dev_c from the host after it is allocated on the device.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot broken in that code you posted, but the core source of the error is that you are attempting to access a host pointer inside the kernel (no memory is ever allocated to `x` on the device and the values are not copied either). Unless you use managed memory, that is obviously never going to work.

You could rework your example into something like this:

```
#include <cstdio>

class cls {
public:
    int *x, y;

    __host__ __device__
    cls(int *x_, int y_) : x(x_), y(y_) {};  

    void kernel();
};

__global__ void kernel1(cls* c){
    printf("%d\n", c->y);
    c->y=2;
    printf("%d\n", c->y);
    c->x[0]=0; c->x[1]=1;
    printf("%d %d\n", c->x[0], c->x[1]);
}

void cls::kernel(){

    int* dev_x; cudaMalloc(&dev_x, sizeof(int)*2);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_x, x, sizeof(int)*2, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cls h_dev_c(dev_x, y);
    cls* dev_c; cudaMalloc(&dev_c, sizeof(cls));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_c, &h_dev_c, sizeof(cls), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    printf("(%d)\n", y);
    printf("(%d, %d)\n", x[0], x[1]);
    kernel1<<<1, 1>>> (dev_c);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaMemcpy(&y, &(dev_c->y), sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(x, dev_x, sizeof(int)*2, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("(%d)\n", y);
    printf("(%d, %d)\n", x[0], x[1]);
}

int main(){

    int y=3;
    int* x=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    x[0]=1; x[1]=2;

    cls c(x,y);
    c.kernel();

    return 0;
}
```

Note that you have to basically build a device copy of the class in host memory and then copy that to the device to make this work correctly (this is a very common design pattern for arrays of pointers or structures and classes containing pointers, although it is almost never recommended for complexity and performance reasons).